# Break Apart a String into Separate Columns R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am trying to tidy up some data that is all contained in 1 column called "game_info" as a string. This data contains college basketball upcoming game data, with the Date, Time, Team IDs, Team Names, etc. Ideally each one of those would be their own column. I have tried separating with a space delimiter, but that has not worked well since there are teams such as "Duke" with 1 part to their name, and teams with 2 to 3 parts to their name (Michigan State, South Dakota State, etc). There also teams with "-" dashes in their name.

Here is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(list(
  game_info = c(
    "12/16 7:00 PM 751 Appalachian State 752 Duke",
    "12/16 7:00 PM 753 Chicago State 754 Indiana-Purdue",
    "12/16 8:00 PM 755 Texas-Arlington 756 Oral Roberts", 
    "12/16 10:00 PM 757 Dartmouth 758 Stanford"
    )
  ))
```

Desired output:

```
date  time     away_team_id  away_team_name     home_team_id home_team_name
12/16 7:00 PM    751         Appalachian State  752          Duke
12/16 7:00 PM    753         Chicago State      754          Indiana-Purdue
12/16 8:00 PM    755         Texas-Arlington    756          Oral Roberts
12/16 10:00 PM   757         Dartmouth          758          Stanford
```

@Jonny Phelps @doRemy

[image]

Comment: Is there a finite set of team names. Instead of using regular expression or comparable strategies, I would maybe replace two worded school names programmatically (grepl) with concatenated versions (e.g. Oral_Roberts) and then retry your original strategy again. It depends on how many team names there are.

Comment: out of curiosity, what file type (.txt, .csv, .xlsx ...) is the data being read from and with which function?

Comment: @rg255 just scraping with rvest from https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/

Comment: could you post the code used to do that? I'm wondering if there is a way to deal with it proactively rather than reactively dealing with the problem - I cannot access the site as I am on a work computer so it's blocked

Comment: I think you should remove one of your tags and put `regex` tag instead.  Since it becomes easier for taking the attentions of the regex geniuses.

Comment: looking at the site on my phone it looks like you're lifting the data from the first column - and that column looks like it's elements are split on to rows by force, i.e. as if there is some kind of tag marking-up those Date/time, Home team and Away team parts

Comment: @Jonny Phelps DoRemy so your solutions worked (when using df above). But after calling str() on my dataframe, it appears there are hidden \t tabspaces in between and not just spaces. I will post a screenshot. My dataframe I have called "table". When I apply your code to table, it returns all NAs (I assume because of the tabspaces and such). When I copy and paste df from above and run your code it works fine.

Comment: Are you able to supply some data with `dput`? I didn't get notified by this, just spotted by change sorry. If it's just `\t` values appearing in the string, maybe try removing them, or replacing with spaces e.g. `gsub("\\\t", "", df$game_info)` or `gsub("\\\t", " ", df$game_info)` where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to use the `extract` from the `dplyr` library with a regex expression:

```
# Define the column names:
column_names <- c("date", "time", "away_team_id", "away_team_name", "home_team_id", "home_team_name")
# Define the regex expression:
regex_expr <- paste(
  "([0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{1,2})", # The date
  "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} [A-Za-z]{2})", # The time
  "([0-9]+)", # The away team id
  "([A-Za-z -]+)", # The away team name
  "([0-9]+)", # The home team id
  "([A-Za-z -]+)" # The home team name
)
# Extract the columns:
df %>% extract(col = game_info, into = column_names, regex = regex_expr)
```

Comment: Much nicer way of presenting the regular expression, I'll take note :)

Comment: Thank you! It does have some limitation in the regex expression since every "group" needs to be in `()`.  For example, you could't write `(AM|PM)` since this would have been considered to be another group (i.e. column).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one with regex. See [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Qx3FpX/1/) for the regex explanations

```
regex <- "^(\\d{2}\\/\\d{2})\\s*(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*(PM|AM))\\s*(\\d+)\\s*([^\\d.]+)(\\d+)\\s*([^\\d.]+)$"

data <- data.frame(game_info=
  "12/16 7:00 PM 751 Appalachian State 752 Duke"
  ,"12/16 7:00 PM 753 Chicago State 754 Indiana-Purdue"
  ,"12/16 8:00 PM 755 Texas-Arlington 756 Oral Roberts"
  ,"12/16 10:00 AM 757 Dartmouth 758 Stanford"
)
library(stringr)

out <- do.call(rbind, str_match_all(data, regex))
out <- as.data.frame(out)
# remove full string & AM/PM
out$V1 <- NULL
out$V4 <- NULL
names(out) <- c("date", "time", "away_team_id", "away_team_name",
                "home_team_id", "home_team_name")
# remove white space from end
out$away_team_name <- trimws(out$away_team_name)
out$home_team_name <- trimws(out$home_team_name)
out
```

**Explanation:**

^(\d{2}/\d{2}) - starts with 2 digits/2 digits like 12/16. ^ is a start anchor and () are used to say we want to capture this group for plucking out

\s* - 0 or more spaces between our first group and the next

(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*(PM|AM)) - want 1 or 2 digits : 2 digits, then possibly a space and PM or AM

\s*(\d+)\s* - spaces around any number of digits, the first id

([^\d.]+) - all non numeric characters. This will fall down if there are ever numbers in your team names. If so, find some examples and we can improve it. White space is captured afterwards so is removed later with trimws

(\d+)\s* - second id and spaces

([^\d.]+)$ - finally the other team name and the end sentence anchor

Comment: I have to learn me some of this regex. +1 - any suggestion for good guide on using it?

Comment: https://regexone.com/ is my favourite tutorial site. I can try picking it apart a bit

Comment: k a quick and dirty explanation is added at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You could use {unglue} :

```r
unglue::unglue_unnest(
  df, game_info, 
  "{date} {hour} {away_team_id=\\d+} {away_team_name} {home_team_id=\\d+} {home_team_name}", convert = TRUE)
#>    date     hour away_team_id    away_team_name home_team_id home_team_name
#> 1 12/16  7:00 PM          751 Appalachian State          752           Duke
#> 2 12/16  7:00 PM          753     Chicago State          754 Indiana-Purdue
#> 3 12/16  8:00 PM          755   Texas-Arlington          756   Oral Roberts
#> 4 12/16 10:00 PM          757         Dartmouth          758       Stanford
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In order to parse it right we must give some regex info, and unglue will "guess" the rest, if we just tell unglue that the ids must be numbers it's enough. `{away_team_name}` is equivalent to `{away_team_name=.*?}`. `convert = TRUE` will put the ids in numeric columns rather than text.

Comment: Cool package, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution requiring only simple pattern matching with `[:digit:]`. The one additional requirement is simply having date and time at the beginning and the character team info in between the number IDs.
Additionally you can use `trimws` on the split list `dspl` to remove unwanted <kbd>TAB</kbd> or similar.

##### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(game_info = c("12/16 7:00 PM 751 Appalachian State 752 Duke", 
"12/16 7:00 PM 753 Chicago State 754 Indiana-Purdue", "12/16 8:00 PM 755 Texas-Arlington 756 Oral Roberts", 
"12/16 10:00 PM 757 Dartmouth 758 Stanford")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

```
dspl <- strsplit( dat$game_info, " +" )

dat_tmp <- cbind( date=as.vector(sapply( dspl, function(x) x[1] )), 
  time=unlist( lapply( dspl, function(x) paste( x[2:3], collapse=" " ) ) ),
  away_team_id=as.vector( sapply( dspl, function(x) x[4] ) ) )

data.frame( dat_tmp, 
  away_team_name=sapply( dspl, function(x) 
    paste(x[ tail( head( grep( "[[:digit:]]", x )[3]:grep( "[[:digit:]]", x )[4], -1 ), -1 ) ], collapse=" ") ), 
  home_team_id=sapply( dspl, function(x) 
    x[ max( grep( "[[:digit:]]", x ) )] ), 
  home_team_name=sapply( dspl, function(x) 
    paste( tail( x[ max( grep( "[[:digit:]]", x ) ):length(x)], -1), collapse=" " ) ) )

   date     time away_team_id    away_team_name home_team_id home_team_name
1 12/16  7:00 PM          751 Appalachian State          752           Duke
2 12/16  7:00 PM          753     Chicago State          754 Indiana-Purdue
3 12/16  8:00 PM          755   Texas-Arlington          756   Oral Roberts
4 12/16 10:00 PM          757         Dartmouth          758       Stanford
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

my_pattern <- "\\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))"

df %>% 
  mutate(date = substr(game_info, 1,5),
         time = str_extract(game_info, my_pattern),
         helper = str_remove(game_info, my_pattern), .keep="unused") %>% 
  mutate(helper = str_squish(str_remove(helper, substr(helper, 1,5)))) %>% 
  separate(helper, c("away_team_id", "away_team_name"), sep = '\\s', remove = FALSE) %>%   
  mutate(home_team_id = str_extract_all(helper, '(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)'),
         home_team_name = sub(".*\\s", "", helper), .keep="unused")
```

```
   date     time away_team_id  away_team_name home_team_id home_team_name
1 12/16  7:00 PM          751     Appalachian          752           Duke
2 12/16  7:00 PM          753         Chicago          754 Indiana-Purdue
3 12/16  8:00 PM          755 Texas-Arlington          756        Roberts
4 12/16 10:00 PM          757       Dartmouth          758       Stanford
```